# How to remove a UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I'm making an application where user add and remove different type of UIImageview ojects to display like hair nose etc. I have done adding images to views only problem i'm facing is how to delete these images I'm using PanGestureRecognizer I want to know to delete the Imageview when dragged to the top see the image Below.

[image]

Comment: Why not just remove the view from its superview?

Comment: there are three different UIViews there one at bottom one at middle and one  at top i want the user to drag an  item to the top if he want to delete it.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Removing a view is trivial, as stated.

Comment: this picture is just a prototype for showing functionality actual app is different.

Comment: People like to help here, me included. But your question is not clear at all. "How can I remove a picture?" Answer: "Remove it from its superview". But this seems not to be your question, so you must write what you mean, because we just cannot guess. If it is "Please write code for me to add a gesture recognizer, move the images along with the tap, than recognize its position and delete it if necessaray" - then, well, it is way to broad, lacks any context, and shows no effort whatsoever to solve problem. Bottom line: If you want a helpful answer, pose a meaningful question.

Comment: It states what you want to do, but not, what your question is. Because implementing it is straight forward, and without your code, how should we be able to find the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

deleting is the wrong word here.

You can remove it from it's superview, which will destroy the imageView IF no other object keep a strong reference to it.

```
[imageView removeFromSuperView];
```

Or you can make it display nil istead of an image which will insure your imageView is still here but it doesn't display anything.

```
imageView.image=nil;
```

if you  wish to delete the displayed image from say a NSMutableArray of extraFeatures, you can :

```
[self.extraFeatures removeObject:imageView.image];
```

and then

```
[imageView removeFromSuperView];
```

** EDIT: pan gesture

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    // move begins
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
      // Do something when the move begin???
      // Maybe record the initial position
    }

    // Move the view around during the pan
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint move = [sender translationInView:self.view];
        sender.view.center = CGPointMake(sender.view.center.x + move.x, sender.view.center.y + move.y);
        [sender setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];

         // test if we should remove the view, viewCenter outside of viewbounds
        if(!CGRectContainsPoint(self.view.bounds, imageView.center))
        {
            [sender.view removeFromSuperView];
        }
    }

    // End of move
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {

        // test if we should remove the view, viewCenter outside of viewbounds
        if(!CGRectContainsPoint(self.view.bounds, imageView.center))
        {
            [sender.view removeFromSuperView];
        }

        // else maybe comming back to the original position
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do it by.

```
self.imageView.image = nil;
```

Comment: You want to use panGesture/Swipe Gesture?

Comment: PanGesture assign to the imageview object and when dragged over the top view image should be deleted

Comment: ok simply alloc and init with target and action.
In your action method write the code i have provide you to remove.
And set the direction to upward.

Comment: Do you want the image also to be animate and then just disappear when user drags the image to upward?
Is it actually you want?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, UIPanGestureRecognizerDirection) {
    UIPanGestureRecognizerDirectionUndefined,
    UIPanGestureRecognizerDirectionUp,
    UIPanGestureRecognizerDirectionDown,
    UIPanGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft,
    UIPanGestureRecognizerDirectionRight
};

static UIPanGestureRecognizerDirection direction = UIPanGestureRecognizerDirectionUndefined;

switch (sender.state) {

    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan: {

        if (direction == UIPanGestureRecognizerDirectionUndefined) {

            CGPoint velocity = [sender velocityInView:recognizer.view];

            BOOL isVerticalGesture = fabs(velocity.y) > fabs(velocity.x);

            if (isVerticalGesture) {
                if (velocity.y > 0) {
                    direction = UIPanGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
                } else {
                    direction = UIPanGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
                }
            }

            else {
                if (velocity.x > 0) {
                    direction = UIPanGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
                } else {
                    direction = UIPanGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
                }
            }
        }

        break;
    }

    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {
        switch (direction) {
            case UIPanGestureRecognizerDirectionUp: {
                [self handleUpwardsGesture:sender];
                break;
            }
            case UIPanGestureRecognizerDirectionDown: {
                [self handleDownwardsGesture:sender];
                break;
            }
            case UIPanGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft: {
                [self handleLeftGesture:sender];
                break;
            }
            case UIPanGestureRecognizerDirectionRight: {
                [self handleRightGesture:sender];
                break;
            }
            default: {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: {
        direction = UIPanGestureRecognizerDirectionUndefined;   
        break;
    }

    default:
        break;
}

}

- (void)handleUpwardsGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Up");
}

- (void)handleDownwardsGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Down");
}

- (void)handleLeftGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Left");
}

- (void)handleRightGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Right");
}
```

Let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: hey this will delete the image when everytime user drag the image to top but i want a particular place(top view) where image is deleted when dragged upon.

Comment: You want when a user drags the image to that particular region of UIView in grey color??
Or You want to remove image when ever user place a gesture on Top UIView that is in grey Color?

Comment: For Case 1: I mean when user drag the image from his current place to top Grey coloured UIView..
You have to get the current and final coordinates and check if the final coordinates are in the range of UIView or not if yes then remove image else do nothing.